# Define “type theory” as a first-order theory

Tags: axiom, type-theory, first-order-logic

I personally conceive of an “nth-order theory”, right now, as:

- an alphabet (*A*)
- a signature (which states the “order” of symbols in the alphabet)
- a single meta-predicate, “equality” or ‘=‘
- a single rule of inference called “substitution” which permits the replacement of expressions on either side of the “equals” symbol.

This may be completely wrong, and I’m looking for corrections to this early-stage, skeletal hypothesis.

The above formulation takes the concept of a “function” as primary. It does not describe quantifiers or variables. It does not mention arity, since multivariate functions can be achieved with currying (I believe). A symbol can only be composed with a symbol of order **one less**. If a symbol is given “order” *n* in the signature, this is understood to mean that **it is not allowed to be followed by any symbol in an equality statement of equal or higher order**. The equality symbol can only be used for expressions of the same “order”. For example:

- a, b are of order 0
- f, g, h are of order 1
- P is of order 2

Therefore,

- the expression “a = b” is allowed
- the expression “a = f” is not allowed (but I want to explore such systems in the future…)
- the expression “f = g” is allowed
- the expression “fa = b” is allowed
- the expression “Pf = g” is allowed
- the expression “Pa = b” is not allowed
- the expression “ab = b” is not allowed

We call such a system “*n*th-order” trivially in relation to its highest order symbol. A “first-order theory” only has symbols of order 0 and 1.

---

The key idea of a “type theory” is apparently that there are fundamental elements of different “types”. We can assume there will be some class of symbols in our alphabet representing these “types”. A type theory also needs a way to express when a thing is *of* a certain type. This sounds like a binary relation, which would clearly be a symbol of order 1. So let’s say we have:

- a collection of zero-order symbols
- a single first-order symbol, “in”, or “is”.

The zero order symbols are the types. The “is” relation expresses type-membership (but we don’t need to worry about “what it means”).

Here is my big issue / question of the hour from here: **When you try to define a type theory as a first order theory / as a signature in some first order language, how is it significantly different from a set theory? Is it a matter of careful selection of different axioms?**

Set theory is also based on a binary predicate conveying “is a member of”.

The axioms of set theory focus on giving structure and definition to that “\member” relation.

For example, the axiom of pairing says that for any two elements a and b, there exists an element c such that a \member c and b \member c.

In type theory, do we want a similar axiom? Actually, yeah, I think we do. This sounds like the “product type” - if A is a type and B is a type, you can form type A x B, with I think the exact same axiom.

I know it’s commonly said that there is a “computational trilogy”, roughly, between sets, types, and categories. But I want to study these ideas more abstractly merely as signatures in a first-order language, to see clearly if their axioms are fundamentally different in syntactic form, and how so.

Comment: For basic notions regarding first-order language, signature, eaulity etc see [Classical Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/) and [Second-order and Higher-order Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/) for the extension of the syntax of predicate logic to "high-order" functions and relations.

Comment: And see [Type Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/) and many related entries: Church's, Intuitionsitic's etc.